# Better way to find two array elements that add up to a given number

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code that works just fine. However I think there may be a **cleaner/better** way of doing this. Basically I have to create a function that takes 2 arguments (array and sum), and return the 2 elements that when adding them together is equals the sum parameter. Does anyone know how to refactor this code or make it simpler?

Here's my code:

```js
var list = [2, 6, 20, 4, 11, 30, 5];
var sum = 9;
var myArray = [];

function findTwoNumbers(arr, sum) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] + arr[j] === sum) {
        myArray.push(arr[i], arr[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return myArray;
}

console.log(findTwoNumbers(list, sum)); // [4 , 5]
```

Comment: Can there be multiple pairs that add up to the sum? If not, you can return as soon as you find a pair, instead of continuing the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I would like to return as soon as I find a pair

Comment: Are the numbers unique?

Comment: @Ry- yes the numbers are unique

Comment: FYI this is literally the first question on **leetcode.com**: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/ and other similar programming question sites. Look at the discussion sections for extensive analysis of viable solutions in various languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is O(N^2). You can reduce it a bit by using a set (though it has a startup cost of constructing the set, so you probably get raw speedup only for large arrays):

```
function findTwoNumbers(arr, sum) {
  const arrset = new Set(arr);
  const answer = arr.find(e => e + e !== sum && arrset.has(sum - e));
  return answer === undefined ? null : [answer, sum - answer];
}
```

Comment: Careful of `findTwoNumbers([2, 5], 4)`, though.

Comment: @progx: The bug is still there, though, so find `e => arrset.has(sum - e) && sum - e !== e` or equivalent.

Comment: @progx: It’s not a very distinct solution, just `&& sum - e !== e` added to the end of the `find` predicate to avoid a number making a pair with itself.

Comment: I just noticed :D

Comment: @Amadan is "has" a ES6 javascript function how about Set?

Comment: Indeed, `Set` is not in ES5. You can fake a set by abusing an object. `const` is also not in ES5, nor is an arrow function. I think even `Array.prototype.find` is not in ES5. If you require an ES5-compatible code, I can do that, though in this day and age it should not be needed. :P

Comment: @Amadan how about the "has" function is it also ES6?

Comment: `has` is not a function, it is a method of `Set` (and one without which `Set` would make no sense). When you get `Set`, you get `has`.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the array into a Set. Then iterate through the array and test whether `sum - element` is in the set.

I need to check for `diff == element` to prevent returning a match from adding an element to itself.

```js
var list = [2, 6, 20, 4, 11, 30, 5];
var sum = 9;

function findTwoNumbers(arr, sum) {
  const set = new Set(arr);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let element = arr[i];
    let diff = sum - element;
    if (diff != element && set.has(diff)) {
      return [element, diff];
    }
  }
}

console.log(findTwoNumbers(list, sum)); // [4 , 5]
console.log(findTwoNumbers([2, 5], 4)); // undefined
```

Comment: Careful in what way? There's no solution, so it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array without the need of external array

```
function findTwoNumbers(arr, sum){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
            if(arr[i] + arr[j] === sum){
                return [arr[i] , arr[j]];
            }
        }
    }

    return [];
}
```

**Note:** This will only search for the first pair that satisfy the condition, there could be more pairs down the iteration path.

Comment: I was looking for something different than having a for loop inside of another for loop since I already got that part. But I'm voting it up. Thanks bro!

Comment: There are other ways as reducing the duplicates entries and then as @Amadan showed you, but for non duplicate numbers it will work the same or event a bit more.

Comment: @OrelEraki: Not sure what you mean by “work the same or even a bit more” but they do have very different performance.

Comment: @Ry- It means for short array the constructing and adding to a Set will be slower, for big array without many duplication this will cost in memory as well, for all other options (which are a lot) the Set solution will be best.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to first sort the array (O(nlog(n)) then traverse the array and for each element, find the difference between (sum - element) and then do a binary search (O(log(n)) for that value.

For example, the first element is 2, so you would binary search the sorted array for 7 (9 - 2 = 7) and if you find it, then 2 and 7 are a pair.  You can stop short too as soon as you reach an element that is greater than (sum/2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you can avoid the binary search here by keeping two pointers into either end of the array and advancing whichever one is closer to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Basically take the sum and subtract the first number in the array to get the remainder, then check if the remainder exists in the array, if not move on to the next.

```js
let list = [2, 6, 20, 4, 11, 30, 5];
let sum = 9;

function findTwoNumbers(list, sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   let n =list[i];
    if (list.includes(sum - n)) {
      return [sum - n, n];
    }
  }
}

console.log(findTwoNumbers(list, sum))
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but `includes` can’t do better than the approach in the question on an array. (It actually takes more steps and has the bug I mentioned on other answers unless you pass `i + 1` as a second argument.) In other words, this is still quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem with your code currently as it will return an array of multiple pairs if there is more than one combination to achieve the sum from the input numbers. So for example:

```
let list = [1, 2, 4, 1];
let sum = 5;
//would give [1, 4, 4, 1];
```

Assuming you want just the first pair, there's no reason to maintain an array (and certainly not one outside the function) - just return immediately:

```
function findTwoNumbers(arr, sum) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] === sum)
                return [arr[i], arr[j]];
}
```

There are further efficiencies and simplicities we can make. Firstly, the loop should ignore any number which is, in itself, higher than sum-1 (since this is the highest a number can be to still achieve the sum with the help of another number, which have to be 1.)

And since it's midnight, how about some pointless syntax sugar?

```
function findTwoNumbers(arr, sum) {
    let nums = arr.filter(num => num < sum);
    return nums.map(num => {
        return nums.filter(num2 => num + num2 == sum)[0];
    }).filter(x => x);
}
```

Comment: The syntax sugar version kind of hurts my soul

Comment: And mine. But hey, he wants something other than nested loops, and I'm very tied. My JS suffers when I'm tired.